# C# ctags configuration for use with vim?

Tags: ctags

I'm trying to find a good configuration for ctags with C#. I know I can use OmniSharp, but I'd like to have tags for other plugins and when OmniSharp is broken.

I started with something based on [this old blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20141116094657/http://www.mad-computer-scientist.com:80/blog/2011/10/06/in-search-of-c-omnicomplete-for-vim/comment-page-1). It didn't include structs.

I also want namespace kind for [inclement](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-inclement).

I added almost all kinds and have been using this for a while:

```
# all C# kinds except:
# e  enumerators (enumeration values) -- just jump to enum instead
# f  fields -- adds 70% more bytes
# l  local variables -- adds 90% more bytes
ctags --c#-kinds=cismpdngtE --fields=+ianmzS --extra=+fq -L $tagfile
```

(Size values are based on a ~10 MB tag file and I find larger tag files result in slower jumps.)

I'm unsatisfied. [Searching github](https://github.com/search?l=Vim+script&p=1&q=ctags+%22--c%23-kinds%22&type=Code) is unhelpful.

For now, I'm trying adding minimal fields info and removing extra info (not entirely sure how extra is used if I don't have vimscript processing it):

```
ctags --c#-kinds=cismpdngtEf --fields=kst -L $tagfile
```

Do you have a better ctag solution for C#?

*Please no lsp/OmniSharp-based solutions.*

Comment: Which ctags are you using? You may get slightly better results with newer, maintained versions

Comment: I'm using ctags 5.9 which is the newest exuberant-ctags release I can find. Looks like [universal-ctags](https://ctags.io/) is no longer considered beta, so I could check that out. However, I still have the problem of how to configure it. (Or are you asserting that it would have better defaults?)

Comment: This has never been answered; did you find a better setting in the meantime you might want to share?

Comment: @DevSolar: My best solution is still the second ctags command in my question. It was sufficient for getting vim-inclement working, but my tags file is still 18 MB and jumps are about as slow as OmniSharp.